# Visual Studio Online Pre-Build step failing

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, pre-build-event

I'm using Visual Studio Online for CI.  I have a Release build set up.  One of my projects has a pre build step which should only be executed for Debug builds.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug copy "$(ProjectDir)Config\web.$(Username).config" "$(ProjectDir)\runtime.config"
```

However VSO fails the build with an error that the command exited with a status of 1.

The same build runs fine when executed using Visual Studio on a developers machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was down to needing brackets on the condition check.  Therefore the following works on VSO.

```
if ($(ConfigurationName) == Debug) copy "$(ProjectDir)Config\web.$(Username).config" "$(ProjectDir)\runtime.config"
```

The brackets are not required for VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

The command must be between parentheses, because is parsed by CMD.EXE

`if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
  copy "$(ProjectDir)Config\web.$(Username).config" "$(ProjectDir)\runtime.config"
)`

See "[if](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true)".